# Elvis operator in a casting invocation chain

Tags: c#, linq, c#-6.0, null-coalescing-operator, null-conditional-operator

The elvis operator, aka null-conditional operator, is massively cool.

In LINQ queries it works great in concert with the null-coalescing "??" operator.

```
Somedata.Where(dt=>(dt?.Inner?.InnerMost?.Include=="Yes")??false);
```

But what do you do if you need to cast the intermediate values?

For one link in the chain, it works out fine.

```
Somedata.Where(dt=>(
     ((InnerClass)dt?.Inner)
     ?.InnerMost)?.Include=="Yes")
     ??false);
```

But with additional necessary casts the cast and invocation are "driven apart".

```
Somedata.Where(dt=>(
     ((InnerMostClass)            <=== Cast
     ((InnerClass)dt?.Inner)
     ?.InnerMost)?.Include=="Yes"))         <=== Use
     ??false);
```

Probably messed up the the parenthesis more than once here, but I hope you get the idea.

Though this "trainwreck" invocation chain is a code smell, is there a more expressive way of doing this to improve succinctness and clarity?

Comment: This may look a little better `((((dt as InnerClass)?.Inner) as InnerMostClass)?.InnerMost)?.Include=="Yes")) ?? false
`

Comment: I can't think of anything better then @Andrey solution, other then, of course, not writing these type of statements in the first place. It's fun to try and squeeze as much functionality into as few lines as possible, but there is code golf for that. For code that people need to maintain, my role of thumb is that if you can't tell at a glance what a lambda is doing, it should be a named function... good question though...

Comment: I'm with pseudoDust: I would scrap that statement. The amount of brain power you have to expend trying to work out what it's doing is a code smell. Also, I'd be concerned about what situation I'd found myself in where I'm having to cast a parent and its children, any of which may be null.

Comment: I'm failing to understand what the problem is related to LINQ. The whole thing looks strange to me. It does smell, but I don't see a problem with LINQ or the null-conditional operator. I could pretty it up with `Cast<T>()` or `OfType<T>()`, but I don't know if it would be better.

Comment: You could write an extension method `SelectCast<T>` which would do `Select(dt=>dt.Inner as T).Where(x=>x!=null)`. Then you can chain them
`Somedata.SelectEx<InnerMostClass>(dt=>dt.Inner).SelectEx<InnerMost>(x=>x.Inner)` and so on... Well, actually you would need several of those methods... I guess it's not worth it :)

Comment: I think @Andrey has it thus far. The code will bloat with parenthesis, but with proper newlines and indentation the end result isn't half bad.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep chaining and prevent the parenthesis by using a very simple extension method:

```
dt?.Inner.As<InnerClass>()?.InnerMost.As<InnerMostClass>()?.Include == "Yes"
```

With the extension method defined like this:

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static T As<T>(this object obj) where T : class
    {
        return obj as T;
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Too bad that we need to use "object" there and ":class" restraint. It would be cool if we could indicate that TInput would need to be an interface or base class of TResult in order to get some compile time check. But in C# that would require both TInput and TResult to be explicit type parameters. The optimum would be for us to only state TResult, but leaving TInput to be inferred. I suppose there is F# in my future..... unless I'm forgetting something.